# is there any possibility to start my hbase from java API?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Is there any way to get master connection from java.. I found one function called getMaster().
Which is deprecated.

Is there any other way to make it possible??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `get master connection`? Are you trying to start the HBase process, or connect to a running instance?

Comment: i m trying to start hbase process from java

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific way to do this in HBase. But you can use the `ProcessBuilder` to achieve it. `ProcessBuilder` can be used to invoke any shell commands, you can check the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for details. Specially, to start HBase, you pass the command `<path_to_hbase_directory>/bin/start-hbase.sh` to `ProcessBuilder`.